# How to Avoid Duplicate field Entry in Google Contacts using gdata api

Tags: python, gdata, gdata-api

I am working on an web application .which basically updates google contacts via gdata client.
i am facing an problem that duplicate fields getting created in contacts based on execution.
i am using the below code

```
contact_entry= self.gd_client.GetContact(contact_url)
contact_entry.website.append(gdata.contacts.data.Website(href='www.fb.com',label='Fb Profile'))
```

when i run 2 the program 2 times .it will create 2 Fb Profile entry in my google contacts..how to override instead of appending.

Any solution is really Appriciated